# Julia finding multiple argmin

Tags: julia, min

I have been trying to find the multiple argmin of the list, and on the explanation part it declares that "If there are multiple minimal elements, then the first one will be returned."

For example,

```
x=[1,-1,-1,2]
argmin(x)
```

It only returned `2`. However, I would like to get `2,3`.
Is there any possible way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have to find that manually with `findall`:

```
findall(==(minimum(x)), x)
```

Note that this is efficient, it will not call `minimum` more than once. The expression `==(minimum(x))` defines a function.